# How to get the entire document text in onDidChangeTextDocument on vscode Language Server implementation?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to parse a file allways that the user change it, so I implement the `onDidChangeTextDocument` method from `connection`.

But this event just give me the URI and the content changes. How can I get the entiry document?

*Obs.:* I also tried to implement the `onDidChangeContent` from `documents`, but it was never called.

Answer (score 5):

The document is in the event passed in to onDidChangeTextDocument. This is how I handle it:

```js
var changeTimeout;
vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(function (event) {
    if (changeTimeout != null)
        clearTimeout(changeTimeout);
    changeTimeout = setInterval(function () {
        clearTimeout(changeTimeout);
        changeTimeout = null;
        backend.reparse(event.document.fileName, event.document.getText());
        processDiagnostic(event.document);
    }, 500);
});
```

This is what MS [writes in the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server#_adding-a-simple-validation):

```js
// The content of a text document has changed. This event is emitted
// when the text document first opened or when its content has changed.
documents.onDidChangeContent((change) => {
    let diagnostics: Diagnostic[] = [];
    let lines = change.document.getText().split(/\r?\n/g);
    lines.forEach((line, i) => {
        let index = line.indexOf('typescript');
        if (index >= 0) {
            diagnostics.push({
                severity: DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
                range: {
                    start: { line: i, character: index},
                    end: { line: i, character: index + 10 }
                },
                message: `${line.substr(index, 10)} should be spelled TypeScript`,
                source: 'ex'
            });
        }
    })
    // Send the computed diagnostics to VS Code.
    connection.sendDiagnostics({ uri: change.document.uri, diagnostics });
});
```

so the document (and so the text) should be available in the event.

Comment: You do this in a language server, or is in the client extension?

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes, this is a client extension, not a language server. Is it different there?

Comment: I think so, because I didn't receive this event.document.. just a params.contentChanges that is an array.. but I discover that this Array return me the entiry file, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do that.

Comment: But this documentation refers to onDidChangeContent, in my case as I describe thi event is never called... So I'm using the onDidChangeTextDocument, that don't have the same change.document

Comment: Then my answer is not good and you should try to find out why you don't get the change event. I'll keep it around however, just in case someone is looking for similar info.

Answer (score 1):

> Obs.: I also tried to implement the onDidChangeContent from documents, but it was never called.

What I wonder is why `onDidChangeContent` stops being called when using any of those: `onDidChangeTextDocument`, `onDidOpenTextDocument`, `onDidCloseTextDocument`. It seems we can only use one way or the other.

So, what you're looking for is this:

```
documents.onDidChangeContent(change => {
  connection.console.log(change.document.getText())
})
```

All `change.document` members: `uri,languageId,version,getText,update,getLineOffsets,positionAt,offsetAt,lineCount`

Answer (score 0):

Usage like for this:

```
import { TextDocument } from 'vscode-languageserver-textdocument'

const documents = new Map<string, TextDocument>()

connect.onDidOpenTextDocument(e => {
  console.log('onDidOpenTextDocument', e.textDocument.uri)
  const doc = TextDocument.create(e.textDocument.uri, 'api', e.textDocument.version, e.textDocument.text)
  documents.set(e.textDocument.uri, doc)
})

connect.onDidCloseTextDocument(e => {
    console.info('onDidCloseTextDocument', e)
  documents.delete(e.textDocument.uri)
})

connect.onDidChangeTextDocument(e => {
    console.log('onDidChangeTextDocument', JSON.stringify(e.contentChanges))
  const doc = documents.get(e.textDocument.uri)
  TextDocument.update(doc, e.contentChanges, e.textDocument.version)
})
```

Comment: `doc.getText()` can get document text